# php call include inside function for outside function use

Tags: php, php-include

I want to `include` a file with php inside of a function, but for it to be used outside of the function.

```
function add( $F ){
    $i = 3;
    while( $i > 0 ){
        $i--;
        try{
            if( ( include $GLOBALS['_SERVER']['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $F ) == 2 ){
                break;
            }
            else{
                sleep( 1 );
            }
        }
        catch( Exception $e ){ }
    }
    die();
}
```

This function is automatically included thanks to `auto_prepend_file`.

index.php

```
add( '/cat.php' );
echo 'my' . $cat;
```

/cat.php

```
$cat = 'cat';
echo '...';
return 2;       //rather not exist but doesnt seem like there's a choice
```

When index.php is loaded: Results in `my...` not `my...cat`.

`include` returns 1 even if a file was included or not. Well, if Notepad++ is 50% finished uploading a file that at the same time was `include`d, it will return 1 and it seems like it just includes a empty file. Which is why `== 2` exists in `add` function.

If I want to include something, I don't want an answer like `you got lucky` or `nope, better luck next time` or `saving was taking too long, enjoy nothing`, or a bunch of code everywhere.

So is this even possible? Or is there a better alternative? Can I use `include_guaranteed` (sarcasm)? I know similar questions were made, but those answers were mainly alternatives to what the user was doing or "why" related.

Comment: "When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available at that line in the calling file will be available within the called file, from that point forward. However, all functions and classes defined in the included file have the global scope." http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: tldr: You can include a file which has functions and classes, but if you are simply doing something like `$cat='cat';` then that variable is within the scope of that function only.

Comment: There are without doubt saner methods to solve whatever it is you are trying to solve, this actually looks like an accident waiting to happen.

Comment: X Y problem: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: @fvu I have countless log errors saying a function does not exist when it was `required`. This function is to make sure `include` actually includes.

Comment: So it looks like @Dagon was spot on ...

Comment: @Dagon It seems that way but I wouldn't say so.